# Java How to get HTML code from URL including AJAX generated code

Tags: html

I'm trying to parse tables using Java, but I get HTML text without tables with data. Tell me the library or the right way to do it. Thank you for any help. Java-8

https://www.tcgplayer.com/categories/trading-and-collectible-card-games/magic-the-gathering/price-guides/khans-of-tarkir

I tried to find answers, but without success

Thank you! Java

Comment: please in the future provide some debugging details and what you have already tried.

Comment: such as, code examples, or libraries you've used. as your current question stands, its more suitable for reddit's webdev subreddit

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use their internal api

call this get api, and supply the amount of rows (set to 5000 by default)

```
GET https://infinite-api.tcgplayer.com/priceguide/set/1356/cards/?rows=5000
```

response

[image]

each result item

[image]

## Code Sample

```java
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class TCGPlayerAPIExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Specify the URL for the GET request
            String url = "https://infinite-api.tcgplayer.com/priceguide/set/1356/cards/?rows=5000";

            // Create a URL object
            URL apiUrl = new URL(url);

            // Open a connection to the URL
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) apiUrl.openConnection();

            // Set the request method to GET
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // Get the response code
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            // Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                // Read the response from the API
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

                // Parse the JSON response
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                // Extract information from the JSON response
                JSONArray cards = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < cards.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject card = cards.getJSONObject(i);
                    String condition = card.getString("condition");
                    double productID = card.getString("productID");
                    double productConditionID = card.getDouble("productConditionID");
                    String game = card.getString("game");
                    double lowPrice = card.getString("lowPrice");
                    double marketPrice = card.getString("marketPrice");
                    String number = card.getString("number");
                    String printing = card.getString("printing");
                    String productName = card.getString("productName");
                    String rarity = card.getString("rarity");
                    double sales = card.getString("sales");
                    String set = card.getString("set");
                    String setAbbrv = card.getString("setAbbrv");
                    String type = card.getString("type");
                    
                    // Process or print the extracted information as needed
                    System.out.println("Card Name: " + cardName);
                    System.out.println("Card Price: " + productID );
                    System.out.println("-----------");
                }
            } else {
                // If the request was not successful, print the error code
                System.out.println("GET request failed. Response Code: " + responseCode);
            }

            // Close the connection
            connection.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***Note**: Code not tested*

Comment: Thank you very much, this is more than enough. Please let me know where you got the link to this list? I want to understand how do I get links for other editions

Comment: sure, @BorisIvanov I openned the website link provided, and then monitored the network traffic, as the page loads, then it loads the data via the api. comman website practice. I used chrome's dev tools, and looked at the network tab, then just reviewed all the top network connections xhr (ajax) and then just found which one was for the table

Comment: @Yogi it is not AI generated, I coded this myself

Comment: @Yogi code is verbose as the OP (poster) is a newbie

Comment: @BorisIvanov remember to up-vote and mark my answer as the solution, if this solved your issue.

Comment: @BorisIvanov remember that abusing this api, will most likely rate-limit or block your device via its IP address